# Как выбрать и вывести данные из БД посредством MySQLi + PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

На вход получаем GET вида localhost/stat.php?c=Russia. Нужно посредством запроса к бд узнать кто "владеет" страной. Т.е значение страны в поле, больше или равно 1. Далее вывести ник-нейм "владельца" и числовое значение в поле через пробел. Если значение равно 0 - вывести "not found". Уточню, значение может быть положительным только в одном поле.
Наличие sql injection уязвимости не играет роли.
Сам я, разумеется, пробовал, но результат вывести не получилось.

Буду очень признателен за код. Вот что у меня.

```
    <?php
$country = $_GET['c'];
// данные доступа к базе данных
$db_host="localhost";   // обычно не нужно изменять
$db_user="??";    // имя пользователя БД
$db_password="??";    // пароль БД
$db_name = "??";  // имя БД

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Ошибка соединения: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

// Выполняем запрос: выбрать пользователей, которые посетили приложение более 10 раз
if ($stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `$country`>0')) {
    // выводим данные
    while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['nickname'].' '.$row['$country'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

[image: Вид БД]

Comment: а можете показать то, что вы пробовали?

Comment: Да, конечно, добавил

Answer (score 1):

С такой архитектурой БД, уязвимость действительно не играет роли :)

Пользователи и страны должны быть в разных таблицах, ваша архитектура БД - это нарушение нормальных форм БД без явной необходимости приводящее вот к таким танцам с бубном (Новая страна - новая колонка)

В самом простом варианте, создайте таблицу country с полями id, name, owner_id, где id primary key, name varchar, owner_id int (внешний ключ на таблицу user (id))

Далее, через JOIN выбирайте влалельца:

`SELECT user.nickname FROM country JOIN user ON user.id = country.owner_id WHERE country.name = 'Russia';`

Если ничего не нашлось, то при пустых результатах возвращайте not found.